# Deciphering of Kurrent handwriting

Tags: meaning-in-context, kurrent

I am transcribing an old philosophical letter, dated 11 May 1892, [image]from the Norwegian Professor of Philosophy Marcus Jacob Monrad (1816-97) to an unknown recipient. Further to this, I have problems with interpreting two XXX highlighted words in the below text/attached picture:

Ich rathe ja nicht über-
haupt das Geschriebene nicht
zu lesen, es ist nur eine Warnung an die
weniger philos.[ophischen] Geschulten oder
der Metaphysik AbXXX,
welche die zunächst folgende
abstr.[akte] Entwickelung nicht
verstehen und
nur in die unrichtige XXX
bekommen wurden.

Answer (score 3):

The words you are looking for are **Abholden** and **Kehle**.

"die [...] der Metaphysik **Abholden**" are "those averse to metaphysics", from adj. *abhold* (with dative: jmdm., einer Sache abhold sein).

(By the way, in that passage, it should be "die weniger *philos[ophisch]* Geschulten" rather than "philos[ophischen]".)

"Die unrichtige **Kehle**" or "unrechte Kehle" is an (antiquated, as far as I can tell) colloquial name for the windpipe (trachea, Luftröhre): see [DWDS, "Kehle"](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Kehle) 1, examples. The idiom "etwas in die unrichtige Kehle bekommen", just as the modern counterpart ["etwas in den **falschen Hals** bekommen"](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/etwas_in_den_falschen_Hals_bekommen), roughly translates to "take sth. the wrong way/be rubbed the wrong way by sth.", especially owing to a misunderstanding. The idiom originates from the literal meaning of the expression, i.e. "to choke on one's food", because the food went into the windpipe as opposed to the gullet – into the *wrong throat*, that is.

A paraphrase: Those lacking a proper philosophical training, or displaying a hostile attitude toward metaphysics, are going to misunderstand the abstract considerations and to be offended by them.